# Isn't the close reason "gaming" a dupe of "off-topic" on Super User?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons

Due to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39523/terminology-issue-of-computer-related-questions), the close reason on Super User `not computer related` has been replaced with `off-topic` now:

[close reasons http://www.imageuploading.com/ims/pic.php?u=19720qFeUy&i=122378](http://www.imageuploading.com/ims/pic.php?u=19720qFeUy&i=122378)

This is much better than it used to be.

But isn't the close reason `gaming` a dupe of that now? `Gaming` is also considered `off-topic` by the [faq](https://superuser.com/faq). I'd vote to remove the `gaming` close-reason.

Comment: sounds good to me.

Comment: Would help reduce the size of the close panel too.

Comment: Thirded filler filler

Comment: @MrStatic: wouldn't that be fourtheded?

Comment: @~quack not anymore.

Answer (score 6):

I would support this change.  Off-topic would include gaming questions IMO.  I will also support anything to reduce the size of the close window in any logical way. I vote to remove the gaming close reason.

Comment: there's an app for that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38680/make-new-close-reasons-dialog-experience-sensitive/38756#38756  (greasemonkey required)

Answer (score 0):

For reference: there's now a gaming SE site.